# How to set-up headers to a newly exported excel file by updating the below macro, which generates new excel file every time it was run?

Tags: vba, excel

The below query generates a new excel file with data from sql server every time it was run. But the generated excel file don't have column headers in it, making it difficult to understand which column is what. So I am interested inserting 5 bold column header names like **column_header1, column_header2....column_header5 in the first row** of the excel and let the **data start from the second row**

```
Sub TEXT()

    Dim cn As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim strCon, strSQL As String
    Dim MRC As Variant

    strCon = "some_string_connection"    
    MRC = "" & Worksheets("SQL Text").Range("D4").Value & ""
    strSQL = MRC    'Sql Query

    Sheets("Summary").Select
    With ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Connection1").OLEDBConnection
        .CommandText = HR
        .CommandType = xlCmdSql
    End With
    ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Connection1").Refresh    

    Folder = "U:\"  'Path in U drive
    Filename = "Filename" & ".xls"
    fpath = Folder & Filename

    cn.Open strCon
    cn.CommandTimeout = 0
    rs.ActiveConnection = cn
    rs.Open strSQL

    Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set A = fs.CreateTextFile(fpath)
    A.Write (rs.GetString(adClipString, , , vbCrLf, ""))

    rs.Close
    cn.Close
    Set cn = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You are writing to the Excel file here:

```
A.Write (rs.GetString(adClipString, , , vbCrLf, ""))
```

Thus, this is the place, where you should put your headers. Something like this should be ok:

```
A.Write "column_header1, column_header2, column_header5" & vbCrLf & _
        rs.GetString(adClipString, , , vbCrLf, "")
```

Comment: Will try what you told, Can you please let me know how to make these headers bold ? Thanks.

Comment: To see the headers bold the best solution is probably to record a macro, while making them bold yourself. The result should be something like `Worksheets(1).Rows(1).Font.Bold = True`

Comment: After adding your headers vba code ,I am getting a vba error saying , run time error 70, permission denied.

Comment: please let me know what to do

Comment: You cannot make text in a text file (CSV) bold - you need to open it in Excel first, and save it as an Excel spreadsheet (XLS / XLSX), and program it while having it open in Excel. Then you you should be able to run Vityata's code above. Although you have named your file as XLS, you are writing to it in CSV format, at least Vityata's code from his answer is. CSV files do not hold formatting information such as boldness.

Answer (score 1):

**There are two method.**

**First method.**

Use rs.field  and variant array.

```
Dim vR() As Variant
Dim str As String

For i = 0 To Rs.Fields.Count - 1
   ReDim Preserve vR(i)
   vR(i) = Rs.Fields(i).Name
Next
```

Second method is add new workbook and write fields and record.

```
If Not Rs.EOF Then
     With Ws
        .Range("a4").CurrentRegion.Clear
        For i = 0 To Rs.Fields.Count - 1
           .Cells(1, i + 1).Value = Rs.Fields(i).Name
        Next
        .Range("a2").CopyFromRecordset Rs
        .Columns.AutoFit
    End With
Else
    MsgBox "There is no record!", vbCritical
End If
```

**First full code.**

```
Sub TEXT()

    Dim cn As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim strCon, strSQL As String
    Dim MRC As Variant

    strCon = "some_string_connection"
    MRC = "" & Worksheets("SQL Text").Range("D4").Value & ""
    strSQL = MRC    'Sql Query

    Sheets("Summary").Select
    With ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Connection1").OLEDBConnection
        .CommandText = HR
        .CommandType = xlCmdSql
    End With
    ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Connection1").Refresh

    Folder = "U:\"  'Path in U drive
    Filename = "Filename" & ".xls"
    fpath = Folder & Filename

    cn.Open strCon
    cn.CommandTimeout = 0
    rs.ActiveConnection = cn
    rs.Open strSQL

    Dim vR() As Variant
    Dim str As String, i As Integer

    For i = 0 To rs.Fields.Count - 1
       ReDim Preserve vR(i)
       vR(i) = rs.Fields(i).Name
    Next

    Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set A = fs.CreateTextFile(fpath)

    str = Join(vR, vbTab) & vbCrLf
    A.Write str
    A.Write (rs.GetString(adClipString, , , vbCrLf, ""))

    rs.Close
    cn.Close
    Set cn = Nothing
End Sub
```

**Second full code.**

```
Sub TEXT2()

    Dim cn As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim strCon, strSQL As String
    Dim MRC As Variant

    strCon = "some_string_connection"
    MRC = "" & Worksheets("SQL Text").Range("D4").Value & ""
    strSQL = MRC    'Sql Query

    Sheets("Summary").Select
    With ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Connection1").OLEDBConnection
        .CommandText = HR
        .CommandType = xlCmdSql
    End With
    ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Connection1").Refresh

    Folder = "U:\"  'Path in U drive
    Filename = "Filename" & ".xls"
    fpath = Folder & Filename

    cn.Open strCon
    cn.CommandTimeout = 0
    rs.ActiveConnection = cn
    rs.Open strSQL

    Dim WB As Workbook, Ws As Worksheet
    Dim i As Integer

    Set WB = Workbooks.Add(Template:=xlWorksheet)
    Set Ws = ActiveSheet
    If Not rs.EOF Then
         With Ws
            For i = 0 To rs.Fields.Count - 1
               .Cells(1, i + 1).Value = rs.Fields(i).Name
            Next
            .Range("a2").CopyFromRecordset rs
            .Columns.AutoFit
        End With
    Else
        MsgBox "There is no record!", vbCritical
    End If
    WB.SaveAs fpath
    WB.Close (0)
    rs.Close
    cn.Close
    Set cn = Nothing
End Sub
```